# What if 2 different sites have different licences for the same object?

Tags: copyright, licensing

I have 2 related questions:

What happens if 2 web pages allow to download the same image but with different licence usage? i.e. one site allows the image for basically every use and the other restrict the usage to only some specific cases

Also, what happens if one author creates one object, and publish it with a very unrestricted licence (like [MIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)), then after some time he changes his mind and changes the licence to a more restricted one, what happens with the derivative work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if 2 web pages allow to download the same image but with different licence usage?

Assuming that both sources are [legitimate] copyright owners of the same object, the licensee should be able to prove that his use of the object complies with the terms of the license from wherever he downloaded it.

> what happens if one author creates one object, and publish it with a very unrestricted licence (like MIT), then after some time he changes his mind and changes the licence to a more restricted one, what happens with the derivative work?

Copyright cannot be enforced retroactively. Derivative works that were created *prior* to the author's change of mind are not affected by subsequent restrictions. Nor does the author's change of mind extend to new creations that derive from derivative works (rather from the author's work) that are covered by the former, unrestricted license even if those new creations occurred after the author restricted the license.